# Simple Knockout + Bootstrap Typeahead plugin race condition

Tags: knockout.js, jquery, knockout-2.0

I have a [very simple Bootstrap Typeahead binding (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh_ca/Fzk4n/4/) for Knockout.js, like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.typeahead = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var $e = $(element),
            source = valueAccessor();

        $e.typeahead({
            source: source,
            minLength: 0
        });
    },
};
```

Its usage is simple:

```
<input data-bind='typeahead: source, value: item,
                  valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
```

The binding works as expected in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh_ca/Fzk4n/4/). However when loaded with RequireJS, it does not always work as expected. There seems to be a race condition as Knockout and jQuery are loading in parallel.

If I look at the `change` event handlers for a bound input element, if jQuery is the handler then the binding works as expected. If Knockout is the handler for the `change` event then, for example, if you type "alp", and Typeahead suggests "Alpha", and you select "Alpha" from the Typeahead dropdown list then the `<input>` element will show the selected text ("Alpha"), but the bound observable will be "alp".

In the current system, the Typeahead binding cannot directly modify the given observables, so passing `{ source: src, observable: item }` would not resolve the issue. The role of this Typeahead binding is only to update the content of the bound input area.

I have experimented with triggering related events from the binding, such as 'keydown', 'keypress' and 'keyup', but for obvious reasons this is not a very resilient option.

I suspect the problem is related to the indeterministic nature of RequireJS, and the Typeahead plugin works or not depending on whether jQuery or Knockout loaded first. In particular, it seems that this problem is resolved by making jQuery a dependency of Knockout (i.e. loading jQuery first) with RequireJS's [`shim`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim):

```
requirejs.config({
   shim: {
      knockout: { deps: ['jquery'] },
   }
 });
```

This seems odd, and I would like to understand better what is happening here and if this is a reasonable resolution of the problem – i.e. am I actually addressing the underlying problem here, or could the issue crop up with subsequent versions of Knockout or jQuery.

I would be grateful for any thoughts.

**EDIT**

You can simply replicate the problem by loading the scripts in-order inline with eg:

```
<script src='knockout.js'></script>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle exhibiting the issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh_ca/Fzk4n/5/)

In the above order the plugin will fail; otherwise it will work as expected.

In any case, the RequireJS config is like this:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: "/script",
  shim: {
    knockout: { deps: ['jquery'] }, # remove this for race condition
  }
});
```

A simplified version of the `main` has `require(['jquery', 'knockout', 'bindings'], ...)`, where `bindings` defines the Knockout handler. The `bindings.js` file effectively starts with `define(['knockout', 'jquery'], ...)`.

In this case though the problem is not RequireJS, but the ordering of the scripts.

Comment: Are you keeping your bindings in a separate module? What's to stop you from ```define(['ko', 'jq'], function(){ //bindings })```? Then in your viewmodel module, you load ```bindings``` as a dependency.

Comment: @JonJaques: Yes, the bindings are in a separate module, which depends on both. The problem seems not to be caused by dependency, but by execution order.

Comment: Hmm, can you post the module code for your viewmodels? Whole thing not needed, just the require stuff, and the portion where you're instantiating/binding the viewmodel?

Comment: You save me some hours with this code! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you're missing a dependency somehow. Likely bootstrap.

See my example here. You're right to look at the shim config.
http://jsfiddle.net/jaquers/sfvy9/2/

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'jQuery.fn.typeahead'  // we can't test for more than one object                   
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Note: the fiddle no longer works, but that code should run if you set up a flat directory structure.

Comment: Thanks Jon. The issue is the ordering of Knockout and jQuery. If jQuery comes first Knockout detects it and uses jQuery event bindings. It seems reasonably safe (based on my cursory knowledge) to expect that Knockout was designed to detect and utilize jQuery and that ordering the scripts so jQuery is loaded first will lead to the expected result. You can see the issue exhibiting in my edit of the question. Cheers